# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json string can not be null or empty

Tags: java, spring, rest-assured, spring-cloud-contract

I have mocked my rest controller using standalone setup and I am getting the below exception. I am using the wiremocks to call external services which are called by my controller. The class below used by spring cloud contract and it will autogenerate the `MockMvcRequestSpecification` and `ResponseOptions` test scenario

**Here is my code.**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public abstract class AccountsControllerContractTest {

@Value("${groups}")
private String groups;

@Value("${service1}")
private String service1;

@Value("${service2}")
private String service2;

private ServiceProvider1 serviceProvider1;

private ServiceProvider2 ServiceProvider2;


@Autowired
WebClient webClient;

    WebClient webClient1 = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(new Consumer<HttpClientOptions.Builder>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(HttpClientOptions.Builder builder) {
            builder.compression(true);
        }
    })).build();

    WebClient webClient2 = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(new Consumer<HttpClientOptions.Builder>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(HttpClientOptions.Builder builder) {
            builder.compression(true);
                       }
    })).build();


    serviceProvider1 = new ServiceProvider1(webClient1, service1, 20);
    serviceProvider2 = new ServiceProvider2(webClient2, service2, tam, 20);

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AccountsController(new EntitlementsService(serviceProvider1, ServiceProvider2))));

   }
 }
```

**Exception**

```
json string can not be null or empty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json string can not be null or empty
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:386)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.ParseContextImpl.parse(ParseContextImpl.java:36)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(JsonPath.java:599)
at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.ContractVerifierTest.validate_shouldGetAccountEntitlements(ContractVerifierTest.java:29)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:108)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

While executing the build, it auto generates the test case and the controller calling the wiremocks (I can see the response in the log). But the controller is not receiving the response back.

Any help?

Comment: It will be easier to help, if you provide the response entity from log.

Comment: seems to be accessor issue, are you using lombok ? Can we see your Providers code ?

Comment: @borino I am not getting any response but the status code is `200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `@Autowired WebApplicationContext context` to the `RestAssuredMockMvc. webAppContextSetup(context)`. Since you're already starting the whole context it makes no sense to use the standalone case. Most likely you're missing a filer or sth so if you pass the whole context it should work better.

Comment: Can you post your sample somewhere? BTW try doing the same but generate your tests in `EXPLICIT` mode and not mock mvc one. You'll have to change the import from `RestAssuredMockMvc` to `RestAssured` AFAIR.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I replaced standalone context with WebApplicationContext but I am still getting the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're getting the same error? Nothing that comes to my mind immediately. You'd have to try to debug this i guess

Comment: Hi Marcin, Yes, I tried debugging and I noticed that in response i.e. MockHttpServletResponse has status 200 code but the content is coming empty.

Comment: I found the issue. I was using  @MockBean on a business class which was in my code and should not have been mocked since original class was already exposed as bean and it executes the business logic. Since the logic was not getting executed the response was coming as null.                                                                                       P.S. - In my case, I didn't change from standalone context with WebApplicationContext and  also didn't use EXPLICIT mode.